# Adding Multidimensional arrays in a specific ways

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, addition

I need a way to execute this such that I get the out put as

```
  var stuck = [["1","2","3"],["2","4","6"],["3","6","9"]]
  var duck = [["bean"],["stalk"],["jack"]]

//i need a output such that

  var output = [["bean","1","2","3"],["stalk","2","4","5"],["jack","3","6","9"]]
```

so the two dimensional array stays as a tow dimensional array and I can use it with my existing code

Comment: Is this Javascript? Add the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the arrays are of equal length:

```
var output = stuck.map((item, i) => {
  return [...duck[i], ...item];
});
```

Comment: thankyou that worked really well, really appreciate that.

Comment: can you explain what is actually happening in the background?(in a way that a newbie can understand)